# keep rows based on conditional value r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of which the following is a representation of the head:

```
ID yesno date1       value1
1  0     NA          NA
1  0     NA          NA
1  0     NA          NA
1  1     2021-01-02  667
1  1     2022-11-02  123
2  0     NA          NA
3  0     NA          NA
3  0     NA          NA
3  1     2022-03-04  111
```

I want to keep only part of the rows of the dataframe, 1 per ID, where the date1 and value1 should be the entries of the first row which depicts yesno == 1. However for IDs which only have yesno == 0, the entries should give NA and not be deleted. Also, the first value1 is not necessarily the largest (as in this example), but the first date1 is the earlierst.
So I want the following output

```
ID yesno date1      value1
1  1     2021-01-02 667
2  0     NA         NA
3  1     2022-03-04 111
```

I hope this clearly states my question. I have tried myself using `dplyr`, however have not succeeded.
Thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `slice_max` to keep the row with the maximum value of `yesno` in each group, it will keep the first occurring of tied maximum values:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice_max(yesno, with_ties = FALSE) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 3 × 4
#      ID yesno date1      value1
#   <int> <int> <chr>       <int>
# 1     1     1 2021-01-02    667
# 2     2     0 NA             NA
# 3     3     1 2022-03-04    111
```